# Asking questions as a software customer without being closed

Tags: discussion, specific-question, off-topic

Yesterday, I asked a question about how separation of layers should be demonstrated to me as a customer of software development. The question was promptly closed as off-topic, to some surprise for me. I still find the question relevant (also for programmers among which I still consider myself) -- even though the question was asked as a client to you as programmers? Being a big Stack Overflow fan, I hope to be able to get input for my new role in the development process here.

Should I go to another Stack Exchange site? Or just cut my ties and realize that I'm with the enemy now? Thinking of the whole agile movement, I assumed that the nature of the interaction between programmers and clients would be relevant to discuss here. Thus I humbly asked how a programmer would go about documenting a specific aspect of an application (in this case layer separation).

Please advise me how to still be able to get input from programmers, without being cut off for being off-topic.

Answer (score 11):

[Your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152330/documentation-of-layer-separation) is off-topic for StackOverflow (how are *we* going to fix the documentation for *their* code), but it may be on-topic for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)*.

<sub>*This is under the assumption your core question is, "what degree of documentation should I require from Software suppliers?"</sub>

Comment: Aha!! I guess the scope is better for programmers. Thanks. Also, you are right about my main question. I was personally thinking in the lines of some kind of test suite dedicated to demonstrate that I can decouple an entire layer -- fx. the GUI -- and replace/stub it.

Comment: @Morten: you're welcome. I would add that when you ask on Programmers be sure to stipulate whether this is for Applications, Libraries, Plugins, Websites, etc. Each of those is likely to have a different degree AND type of documentation required. They each will have a different degree/type of verification and validation required too. Good luck.